# "Knowing Language know grammar is easy." Is the sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, punctuation

*"Having a lot of money have respect for others is not easy."*

Are my sentences correct, does it need any punctuation mark ?
Please Explain me.

I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

No, the sentence is not correct. I, personally, can not comprehend what you are trying to say. The main issue is that **there is no connecting word/phrase between "having a lot of money" and "have respect for others".** There is no "subject" in the sentence, or at least not a clear one - *what* is not easy?

You can check [this out,](https://www.really-learn-english.com/sentence-structure.html) it may help out a bit.

Comment: I agree. I also don't know what you are trying to say. In most contexts, the subject cannot be omitted in English.

Comment: What alternatives can be used for what I want to say?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu can you explain what you are trying to say? Are you trying to say that having a lot of money AND having respect for each AT THE SAME TIME is not easy?

Comment: Exactly, sir, I am trying to say the same.

Comment: I didn't get satisfactory answer.